# How to handle empty column in parsing with CsvHelper?

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I have a CSV file, I'm trying to parse it, But getting the below error on int datatype column.In the file, I'm passing the blank or empty value for this column.

```
[AutoMap(typeof(Test))]
[FileEntity("Test")]
public class TestFileEntity : BaseFileEntity
{
    [CsvFileColumn(1)]
    public int TestId { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<BaseFileEntity> Parse(Stream masterData, Type entityType, out IEnumerable<MasterDataFileParserError> errors)
{
    var list = new List<BaseFileEntity>();
    var errorList = new List<MasterDataFileParserError>();

    try
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(masterData))
        {
            var parser = new CsvReader(reader, new CsvHelper.Configuration.Configuration
            {
                HasHeaderRecord = true,
                HeaderValidated = null,
                MissingFieldFound = null
            });

            list.AddRange(parser.GetRecords(entityType).Cast<BaseFileEntity>());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex.Data == null || ex.Data.Count == 0)
        {
            errorList.Add(new MasterDataFileParserError
            {
                Error = ex.Message,
                Description = ex.ToString()
            });
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var key in ex.Data.Keys)
            {
                errorList.Add(new MasterDataFileParserError
                {
                    Error = ex.Message,
                    Description = $"{key}: {ex.Data[key]}"
                });
            }
        }
    }

    errors = errorList;

    return list;
}
```

Exception in this line: `list.AddRange(parser.GetRecords(entityType).Cast<BaseFileEntity>());`

Error:

> An error has occurred while parsing 'xyz.csv' file for 'Test' entity:
>   '[{"Error":"The conversion cannot be performed.\r\n    Text: ''\r\n
>   MemberType: System.Int32\r\n    TypeConverter:
>   'CsvHelper.TypeConversion.Int32Converter'","Description":"CsvHelper.TypeConversion.TypeConverterException:
>   The conversion cannot be performed.\r\n    Text: ''\r\n    MemberType:
>   System.Int32\r\n    TypeConverter:
>   'CsvHelper.TypeConversion.Int32Converter'\r\n   at
>   CsvHelper.Configuration.Configuration.<>c.<.ctor>b__148_4(CsvHelperException
>   exception)\r\n   at
>   CsvHelper.CsvReader.d__65.MoveNext()\r\n   at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.d__34`1.MoveNext()\r\n   at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddEnumerable(IEnumerable`1
>   enumerable)\r\n   at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1.InsertRange(Int32 index,
>   IEnumerable`1 collection)\r\n   at
>   Nec.Stanchion.Business.MasterDataFiles.Handling.MasterDataFileParser.Parse(Stream
>   masterData, Type entityType, IEnumerable`1& errors) in xyz.cs
>   file"}]'.

The reason is very clear, that blank or empty string is not compatible with `int` datatype, so there has to be some way to allow empty or null value with `int` datatype column value.

**CsvHelper Version=6.0.0.0**

Comment: It sounds like you should change your datatype to a nullable int (`int?`).

Comment: I have already tried making nullable, but not working

Comment: @viveknuna You might need to sanitize by attempting to convert to proper type on object, I provided a solution below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm using CsvHelper 6.1.0 in my current project, just tested a use case similar to yours, int field in blank in the csv file, and had no problem. This is the code I'm using, hope it helps:

```
        CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream()));
        csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<PessoaCSVMap>();
        csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ";";
        csv.Configuration.HeaderValidated = null;
        csv.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = null;
        List<Pessoas> pessoas = csv.GetRecords<Pessoas>().ToList();
```

---

```
public sealed class PessoaCSVMap : ClassMap<Pessoas>
{
    public PessoaCSVMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Nome).Name("Nome", "Name");
        ... etc
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you nailed it.  Configuration didn't know how to handle object.  After he responded with more information an documentation was going to update answer, I'll delete cause you more than likely have the exact fix.

Comment: But how is it going to work in my case? Can you please explain your code a bit?

Comment: Where’s the handling for blank or empty properly?

Comment: No handling needed - it just works. Int fields that are blank in the csv will be null in the object.

Comment: Documentation is here: http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/mapping.

Any more doubts, I'll be glad to help.

Comment: What’s the significance of PessoaCSMap class?

Answer (score 5):

I also had this problem, of null/ other problematic values that are not excepted in double or decimal objects

The best solution I've found goes like this:

```
   //first inject the class map
   CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(new 
   StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream()));
   csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<SomeEntityClassMap>();
   var records = csv.GetRecords<SomeEntity>().ToList();
 
public class SomeEntityClassMap : ClassMap<SomeEntity>
{
    public SomeEntityClassMap()
    {
        //use the converter on double or decimal types
        Map(x => x.Price).TypeConverter<DoubleConverter>();
        Map(x => x.Cost).TypeConverter<DoubleConverter>();
    }
}

public class DoubleConverter : DefaultTypeConverter
{
    public override object ConvertFromString(string text, IReaderRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {
        if(double.TryParse(text, out var result))
            return result;

        return 0;
    }
}
```