# Exception converting string to decimal

Tags: csvhelper

Exception in csvhelper converting '' to decimal.

I've searched for several hours today and tried all the possible solutions including a custom converter, many of those are outdated and do not work in v12.1.2

Unhandled Exception: CsvHelper.TypeConversion.TypeConverterException: The conversion cannot be performed.
    Text: ''
    MemberType: System.Decimal

As a quick workaround I replaced all empty fields with zero.

Comment: this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48426362/how-to-handle-empty-column-in-parsing-with-csvhelper

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my issue. The last row only had an entry for the first field and all others were empty.

csv.Configuration.ShouldSkipRecord = (x) => x[0].StartsWith("--this is the end of report--");